# Couldn't calcaulate the IP checksum correctly

Tags: c++, c, networking

Have been stuck in this problem for several days. Could anyone help me please?

The core code:

### IP header

```
ip_hdr
{
    unsigned char   h_ver;
    unsigned char   tos;
    unsigned short  tot_len;
    unsigned short  id;
    unsigned short
        zero:1,
        frag:1,
        more_frag:1,    
        frag_off:13;            
    unsigned char   ttl;
    unsigned char   protocol;
    unsigned short  checkSum;
    unsigned long   saddr;
    unsigned long   daddr;
}
```

### The checksum function

It's from the source code of linux so I assume that it works properly.

```
unsigned short checkSum(unsigned char * buff, int wlen)
{
    unsigned long sum = 0;

    if (wlen) {
        unsigned long bogus;
        __asm__("clc\n"
            "1:\t"
            "lodsl\n\t"
            "adcl %3, %0\n\t"
            "decl %2\n\t"
            "jne 1b\n\t"
            "adcl $0, %0\n\t"
            "movl %0, %3\n\t"
            "shrl $16, %3\n\t"
            "addw %w3, %w0\n\t"
            "adcw $0, %w0"
            : "=r" (sum), "=S" (buff), "=r" (wlen), "=a" (bogus)
            : "0"  (sum),  "1" (buff),  "2" (wlen));
    }
return (~sum) & 0xffff;
}
```

### Generate an IP datagram

```
int IPGen(ip_hdr *hdr,unsigned long srcIP,unsigned long dstIP)
{
    hdr->h_ver=(4<<4 | sizeof(ip_hdr)/sizeof(unsigned int));
    hdr->tos=0;
    hdr->tot_len=sizeof(ip_hdr)+sizeof(tcp_hdr);
    hdr->id=0;
    hdr->zero=0;
    hdr->frag=0;
    hdr->more_frag=0;
    hdr->frag_off=0;
    hdr->ttl=64;
    hdr->protocol=IP_TCP;
    hdr->saddr=srcIP;
    hdr->daddr=dstIP;

    hdr->saddr=htonl(hdr->saddr);
    hdr->daddr=htonl(hdr->daddr);
    hdr->tot_len=htons(hdr->tot_len);

    hdr->checkSum=0;
    hdr->checkSum=checkSum((short*)hdr,sizeof(ip_hdr));

    return 0;
}
```

The packets generated in this way are thought `invalid` by wireshark... Splendid when red took up most of the space

Here comes the most weird things,I captured a packet with wireshark then calculate its checksum and I found that the result I get is unequal to that contains in the packet.

Comment: You should also find an example of this function being used in Linux, and compare it to how you're using it.

Comment: You are passing a count of bytes in the second argument to `checkSum`, but the online assembler treats it as a count of `uint32_t`.

Comment: solved!!!!my g++4.7.1 treat the count parament in checkSum as the count of uint32 instead of char!!

Comment: @Casey sincerly appreciate!!:-)